# Looping through GridView rows and validating each TextBox contained within an ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, validation, webforms

I have a databound textbox within a gridview which enables the user to easily and quickly bulk update rows. I have tried to use the CustomValidator to validate each textbox against a SQL column but it doesn't behave the way I need it to. The CustomValidator code works properly in the TextChanged event, however it does not behave properly in the ServerValidate event (I understand why). If I leave the code in the TextChanged event handler it still allows the data to be modified when hitting the Update button I created. What can I do to validate each TextBox individually and effectively against the SQL data?

```html
    <ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="Account" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="Account_TextChanged" Text='<%# Bind("Account") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="CustomValidator" ValidateEmptyText="false" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="Account" OnServerValidate="Validate_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="Custom Validator"></asp:CustomValidator>
</ItemTemplate>
```

```cs
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
{
    TextBox Account = row.FindControl("Account") as TextBox;
    CustomValidator validator = row.FindControl("CustomValidator1") as CustomValidator;
    string sAccount = Account.Text;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Account Table WHERE Account = @Account", conn))
        {
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Account", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters["@Account"].Value = sAccount;
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        validator.IsValid = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        validator.IsValid = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: i would like to see the code you were using to validate server side.

Comment: It is included in the post, starts with the foreach. When I run it in the ServerValidate method it runs through all rows for each row so if you have 10 columns it runs 100 times and does not validate properly. I expect this behavior, however I do not know how to get the textbox value for each row without looping through the grid. It works properly in the TextChanged method, but it doesn't stop the update from happening when the Update button is clicked.

Comment: why don't you store the values in a data table or something and validate that?

Comment: I could but then I'd be validating the entire table, I need to validate the individual textboxes. I want a warning message on the textboxes which contain invalid values, not on every textbox, or one warning for the entire page.

Comment: @tunacode ok um add a validation group to your text box and your validator and call 'page.validate("group");' , maybe that will do it for you

Comment: @tunacode, being that there is one validator in each cell you dont need to for each, should just validate the specific text box for that validation, when you call IsValid() should call it for each validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would want to do something like

Front Page:

```
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtValidateMe"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="validateTheTextBox" OnServerValidate="validateTheTextBox_OnServerValidate" ControlToValidate="txtValidateMe"/>
```

Server Side

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate();
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }

    protected void validateTheTextBox_OnServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString))
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Account Table WHERE Account = @Account", conn))
        {
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Account", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters["@Account"].Value = args.Value;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this handled by moving the validation logic out of the ServerValidate Event and into an update buttonclick event.

```
protected void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow row in SomeGrid.Rows)
                {
                    TextBox SomeTextBox = row.FindControl("SomeTextBox") as TextBox;
                    CustomValidator validator = row.FindControl("SomeValidator") as CustomValidator;
                    string Account = SomeTextBox.Text;
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Account FROM Account WHERE Account = @Account", conn))
                    {
                        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Account", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                        da.SelectCommand.Parameters["@Account"].Value = Account;
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            validator.IsValid = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            validator.IsValid = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```